# typescript: How to define type as any part of enum?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generics, enums

I'm trying to create a translation module using typescript.

I want to define the languages as an enum parameter to create-text function, as like:

```js
export enum Language {
    He = "he",
    En = "en",
}
const { createI18n, createI18nText } = createTextFunctions(Language);
const firstExample = createI18nText({
    he: {
        firstText: "שלום",
        sc: {
            hello: "שלום שוב"
        }
    },
    en: {
        firstText: "hello",
        sc: {
            hello: "hello again"
        }
    }
})
export const i18n = createI18n({
    welcome: firstExample,

})
```

But my problem is that because the languages are are passed as params to a typescript function and the function infers the types, typescript is not alarming anything. I can create text with non-existing language and it will pass it,like `createI18nText({ ar:{ hi : "hi" }})`.

My text functions are these:

```js
export type Languages = { [key: string]: string };
export const createTextFunctions = (languages: LanguagesD) => {

    type I18nText<T extends object> = {
        [k in keyof typeof languages]: T;
    }

    const createI18n = <T extends { [key: string]: I18nText<any>; }>(i18n: T) => {
        return i18n;
    };

    const createI18nText = <T extends object>(text: I18nText<T>) => {
        return text;
    }

    return {
        createI18n,
        createI18nText
    }
}
```

So the code is running and doing whatever it needs to do, but I'm losing type control.

I do prefer to have my enum values lower-cased, so its an issue too. If this is the solution so I'll take it, but if there is any way to pass an enum-param and to run by its values it would be great.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBP7pW) work for you to limit the language names to what's passed in?  If not, please elaborate on what's missing. Otherwise I can write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `createTextFunctions` use a generic. You will be able to customise the keys as you want when you create the text function :

```
// *L* must be a union of strings.
const createTextFunctions = <L extends string>() => {

    type I18nText<T extends object> = Record<L, T>;
    type I18n = Record<string, I18nText<any>>;

    const createI18n = <T extends I18n>(i18n: T): T => {
        return i18n;
    };

    const createI18nText = <T extends object>(text: I18nText<T>): I18nText<T> => {
        return text;
    }

    return {
        createI18n,
        createI18nText
    }
}
```

Then specify the `Language` as a union of strings:

```
type Language = "en" | "he";
```

And create/use the text functions:

```
const { createI18n, createI18nText } = createTextFunctions<Language>();

const firstExample = createI18nText({
  he: {
    firstText: "שלום",
    sc: {
      hello: "שלום שוב"
    }
  },
  // If the key *en* is missing, typescript will complain.
  en: {
    firstText: "hello",
    sc: {
      hello: "hello again"
    }
  },
  // If we add the key *us*, typescript will complain.
})

export const i18n = createI18n({
  welcome: firstExample,
})
```

IMO union types are more comfortable to use than enums.

Comment: Thank you! It works, but I still prefer enum. @jcalz comment worked as well. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as answered then ;)